# If a number is in a range tell me the name of the range. (the value in the next column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table if ranges of number and the name of each range like that:

```
Color   Wavelength (nm)
Red 626 - 740
Orange  591 - 625
Yellow  566 - 590
Green   521 - 565
Cyan    501 - 520
Blue    436 - 500
Violet  380 - 435
```

| Color Wavelength (nm) |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 626 | 740 |
| Orange | 591 | 625 |
| Yellow | 566 | 590 |
| Green | 521 | 565 |
| Cyan | 501 | 520 |
| Blue | 436 | 500 |
| Violet | 380 | 435 |

Then in a column I have a long list of numbers and i have to tell the color of the number.

The list is not just that, all de electromagnetic spectrum is in this list of ranges.

How can I make this work without a gigantic IF inside IF chain?

For shorter lists I usually make a chain of IFs one for each interval.

But this will be too big.

Comment: Please provide input data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format and provide expected output

Comment: Added markdown format. Pls. apply it in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I was having trouble doing it. Won't happen again. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Xlookup:

```
=IF(E2<B$8,"",XLOOKUP(E2,C$2:C$8,A$2:A$8,"",1,-1))
```

Or as a spill formula:

```
=LET(inputs,DROP(TOCOL(E:E,1),1),
IF(inputs<B8,"",XLOOKUP(inputs,C2:C8,A2:A8,"",1,-1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pls. try this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF((E2>=B$2:B$8)*(E2<=C$2:C$8),A$2:A$8,""))
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this in another sheet, this one is very clever for other situation. Thank you.

Comment: Advantage of this formula that not require a contiguous table of the limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel365 - use `FILTER()`. Use multiplication as `AND()` equivalent for multiple criteria.

This example on screen returns `"Yellow"`.

`=FILTER(ColorNames,(MinWavelength<=WaveLengthValue)*(MinWavelength>=WaveLengthValue))`

[image: Filter color names by wavelength]

If you want to run this function across the whole table at once, wrap it with `MAP()` and `LAMBDA()`. This function will scan the array of wavelengths and return a range of all filters, run one by one.

[image: Use of MAP() with above]

```
=MAP(WaveLengthRange,LAMBDA(WaveLengthValue,(=FILTER(ColorNames,(MinWavelength<=WaveLengthValue)*(MinWavelength>=WaveLengthValue))
```

Comment: Please note that this code assumes all Wavelength values are integers! In your example, a wavelength of 500.5 will fall in between and will be not found. Change either <= or => sigh to < or > respectively if you want to text for fractional wavelengths.

Comment: Thank you, this one is very well made, I will try and learn more about LAMBDA and MAP.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you, this one is very well made, I will try and learn more about LAMBDA and MAP.
Thanks

Comment: MAP() is a method to force a formula that returns only single values to return arrays. Sometimes if you pass to formula as array as argument, it returns an error. For example, if I give FILTER() a range and tell "Filter the data for every value in a range" it will reply - "#NA, not going, too much work". However if I give MAP() the same range and say "Here are some random values, take them one by one, call em WaveLengthValue, feed them to FILTER() and return all results as a range" - it reports "Aye sir! At once! You FILTER() get on your feet, and do what I tell you". So, here.